# Firestore rule for unauthenticated users holding a secret key

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of Blobs. A Blob should be readable by any user (authenticated or not) only if the user knows a secret stored in the Blob. Any other read must require the currently logged in user to be the owner of the Blob.

Here's a Blob:

```
{
    name: "helo",
    owner: {
        "uid-101": true
    },
    secret: "abc123"
}
```

And here's my current security rule that enforces an authenticated user to be the owner of the Blob in order to read it:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /blobs/{id} {
      allow read: if resource.data.owner[request.auth.uid] == true 
    }
  }
}
```

So the question is: how can I add a rule that would allow **unauthenticated** users to do this:

```
var query = blobsRef.where("secret", "==", "abc123")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this use-case is currently possible, since I don't know if the `where` properties are available in the security rules. But if they are, you'll have to do something like `allow read: if request.query.orderBy['secret'] === resource.data.secret`.

Comment: That could potentially work, at least in javascript which accepts any key-value pair for orderBy. But in Swift the SDK only allows a Boolean: `order(by: String, descending: Bool)`.